# TypeErr: Object "int" is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to make a "typing game" and at first, it worked out pretty nice. But when I translated my code to English (variable names, class names, function names etc.) it gave me the warning "Object int is not callable". How can I solve this?

Here's my code:

```
import time
import random
import sys

class Player():
    def __init__(self, name, health = 5, energy = 10):
        self.name = name
        self.health = health
        self.energy = energy
        self.hit = 0

    def inf(self):
        print("Health: ", self.health, "\nEnergy: ", self.energy, "\nName: ", self.name)
    def attack(self, opponent):
        print("Attacking")
        time.sleep(.300)
        for i in range(3):
            print(".", end=" ", flush=True)
        x = self.randomAttack()
        if x == 0:
            print("Nobody attacks.")
        elif x == 1:
            print("{} hits {} !".format(name, opponentName))
            self.hit(opponent)
            opponent.health -= 1
        elif x == 2:
            print("{} hits {}!".format(opponentName, name))
            opponent.hit(self)
            self.health -= 1
    def randomAttack(self):
        return random.randint(0, 2)
    def hit(self, hit):
        hit.hitVariable += 1
        hit.energy -= 1
        if (hit.hitVariable % 5) == 0:
            hit.health -= 1
        if  hit.health < 1:
            hit.energy = 0
            print('{} won the game!'.format(self.name))
            self.exit()
    @classmethod
    def exit(cls):
        sys.exit()
    def run(self):
        print("Running...")
        time.sleep(.300)
        print("Opponent catch you!")

#######################################################

print("Welcome!\n----------")

name = input("What's your name?\n>>>")
opponentName = input("What's your opponent's name?\n>>>")

you = Player(name)
opponent = Player(opponentName)

print("Commands: \nAttack: a\nRun: r\nInformation: i\nExit: e")

while True:
    x = input(">>>")

    if x == "a":
        you.attack(opponent)

    elif x == "r":
        you.run()

    elif x == "i":
        you.inf()

    elif x == "e":
        Player.exit()
        break

    else:
        print("Command not found!")
        continue
```

It gives me the error at line 24 (self.hit(opponent)).

Comment: You've got a function and a field both called `hit`, change one of them

Comment: Thanks. This solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `hit` function is the problem. You have member and a function with the same name. Change one of them.

Also rename the hit argument of the `hit()`. You call it via self.hit(opponent) so I would rename it to `def hit(self, opponent):`.

```
def __init__(self, name, health = 5, energy = 10):
        self.hit = 0


def hit(self, hit):
        hit.hitVariable += 1
        hit.energy -= 1
        if (hit.hitVariable % 5) == 0:
            hit.health -= 1
        if  hit.health < 1:
            hit.energy = 0
            print('{} won the game!'.format(self.name))
            self.exit()
```